# How drag an Item and drop to different tab/window using React DND?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

The scenario is, I want to **Drag** an element and **Drop** into a different Window/Tab. I am using [React DND](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/about) for Drag and Drop.

There are hardly any examples available for Dragging and Dropping between Tabs. It would be helpful if you can share the path or example which I can follow to solve this.